# How to calculate a rank on monthly basis in java by using lambda Expressions?

Tags: java, lambda

I am trying to calculate A rank based on percentage by monthly wise. But Currently, with the help of Lambda expressions Rank is getting based on year wise. So how to calculate it based on a month.

**Here is the code which I tried :**

```
List<MVisitsBean> summaryScore = rDao.getdealer_performance(mvBean,mvBean.getYear(),mvBean.getMonth(),mvBean.getRegion_id(),mvBean.getOutlet_id(),mvBean.getBrand_id(),mvBean.getDealer_id(),mvBean.getLimit(),total);

          double[] score = {Double.MIN_VALUE};
             int[] no = {0};
             Integer[] rank = {0};
             List<MVisitsBean> ranking = 
                     summaryScore.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(MVisitsBean::getYtd_dealer_avg1).reversed())
                 .map(p -> {
                     ++no[0];
                     if (score[0] != p.getYtd_dealer_avg1()) rank[0] = no[0];
                     p.setYtd_dealer_rank(rank[0]);
                     return new MVisitsBean(rank[0], score[0] =  p.getYtd_dealer_avg1());
                 })
                 // .distinct() // if you want to remove duplicate rankings.
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
             System.out.println(ranking);

                String jsonArray = gson.toJson(ranking);
                System.out.println(jsonArray);
```

Comment: That seems complex. Wouldn't it be easier to a simple for loop?

Comment: yes, but mine requirement is to modify this snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You want to calculate Months instead of Years. So this bean:

```
List<MVisitsBean> summaryScore = rDao.getdealer_performance(mvBean,mvBean.getYear(),mvBean.getMonth(),mvBean.getRegion_id(),mvBean.getOutlet_id(),mvBean.getBrand_id(),mvBean.getDealer_id(),mvBean.getLimit(),total);
```

It calculates from the year and month. I assume that if you change the getYear to getMonth and the getMonth to getDay (I'm assuming this bean have something like "getDay") it should be ok.

Then on your stream:

```
      List<MVisitsBean> ranking = 
                 summaryScore.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(MVisitsBean::getYtd_dealer_avg1).reversed())
             .map(p -> {
                 ++no[0];
                 if (score[0] != p.getYtd_dealer_avg1()) rank[0] = no[0];
                 p.setYtd_dealer_rank(rank[0]);
                 return new MVisitsBean(rank[0], score[0] =  p.getYtd_dealer_avg1());
             })
```

I don't know exactly what each argument do in the bean. But I'm assuming that:

```
MVisitsBean::getYtd_dealer_avg1
```

Is something with the year of the bean.
You should find something related to the Month, like:

```
MVisitsBean::getMtd_dealer_avg1
```

In the bean and update your getter and setter in the Stream (getYtd_dealer_avg1, setYtd_dealer_rank).

Otherwise, it's difficult do answer more precisely without knowing your MVisitsBean structure.

Hope it'll helps.